# What is a context for client server model?

Tags: linux, client-server

I am working on a C++ program running on linux machine. I am new to client server architecture. I recently get to know that the program I'm working on use something called context, so that the client can set the various configuration like access-mode etc to communicate with the server accordingly.

I want to know if it is something that is specific to my program or it is the same concept anywhere? And is it called context as a general term or it has some other common names? Any guide in the right direction will be helpful.

**Update:**
I can feel that it is too broad of a concept to answer. I am particularly curious about where this concept fits in the client-server architecture?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many protocols use a context which is changed with the commands sent by the client. If you program a FTP, POP, or IMAP server, the context will contains wether the user is successful logged, and who is he. Then, the command which ask a list of files or a list of emails can either return a list depending of who is logged or reject this command.

If you implement the server with a multithread program, each thread will have an object given as a parameter which contains the context each thread will read and update. If you program the server with a multi process program (like Apache), a set of global variables (different between each process) can contain the context.